# New to linux and trying to update from 21.10 to 22.04.1

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, repository

I downloaded ubuntu 21.10 a while back and made it my main OS but since have rarely used my PC
I am a novice with Ubuntu and encountering difficulties when trying to update.

This error appears when I run sudo apt-get update

```
Error:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu impish Release        
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: sudo apt-get update doesn't fully upgrade the Latest O.S. Maybe try ```do-release-upgrade ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) 21.10 is now EOL

Comment: The warning about 21.10 being EOL (six weeks before) and again at EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/) include the upgrade instructions.  You're now beyond that date, thus have an extra step covered in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades as your archives are *gone* (due to EOL) and need to be ***manually*** corrected to allow for this (*a step that isn't required whilst release is supported, or briefly after EOL*)

Comment: PPAs however being 3rd party sources, are free to *drop* support for any EOL release (*the official ones tend to do that, as updated builds are no longer possible*) which may thus require manual intervention.  You should *release-upgrade* whilst release is supported, as the *drop* or *move* is only listed as occurring **after** the EOL, so it maybe the next day, or many weeks after the EOL.